# Error generating route "/": HTML minification failed. Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js, netlify

I developed a nuxt app and it works perfectly when run with "npm run dev". But when I generating the site with "npx nuxt generate" console shows following error. I cant find the error. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: The main difference between those two processes is that `nuxt generate` will use SSR to create the html and other assets. Running dev or build compiles the information into a js file and might use SSR depending on your settings. So, this error means that something is occurring during the SSR process that prevents the HTML generation.

Comment: @RobotOptimist Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. There were two reasons for that in my case.

1. There were some css classes in html which are not defined in css file.
2. There were pictures with broken links and some are not exist in source folder.

Answer (score 2):

Mine was actually because I had some form of "<" and ">" which probably interfered with the HTML (?)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case it was caused by a wrong `<br>` - tag.

```
I've used `</ br>` instead of `<br />`.
```

A short annotation. Chrome accepts `</br >` - tag and renders the page like expected, but the html minifaction does not work properly.